# How to create AD users that match to Azure AD Accounts

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

What is my problem:

We started with AzureAD and are currently at the point where we use our laptops and login with account emails. The devices are shown as "joined" to the azure AD.

Now I want to create an on-premise Primary Domain Controller to manage the user there but have SSO.

Problems to solve: 
We already have several employees and all laptops are setup and fully installed. I would like it to behave the way that nothing changes for the users. All data should be were it was before.
Login with email address as usual and have all the data and programs as installed. So I like a mapping of the "local" user information. Just to clarify: There is no real local account it is only a azure ad account.
If a user changes his/her password it should be syncronized (using ADConnect).

What I have found:
If I use Azure Active Directory Services instead (I would not care if it is Azure or onpremises actually) this would mean for my understanding I have to create a VPN as well and make a site-to-site VPN. So I need a VPN endpoint in my local network as well.

So creating a Domain Controller locally I have the problem that I cannot replicate the AzureAD accounts locally. But from reading I understand that I could
match my newly created user accounts in the DC to the accounts in AzureAD for syncing. There are some articles online to achieve this if I didn't miss a point from the information I
got from:

https://www.itpromentor.com/soft-vs-hard-match/
https://flamingkeys.com/immutableid-azure-ad/
https://www.e-apostolidis.gr/microsoft/office-365/match-onprem-active-directory-users-existing-office365-users/

So I possibly could:
- create a PDC.
- create users.
- make them sync to the corresponding AzureAD accounts.

But then the question is:
Does it solve my problem?
Can I add the devices (laptops) to the PDC and then log in with the email addresses as usual and it will recognize the correct locally saved data in desktop etc?
And will it be possible to view encrypted folders from these users (because they will be recognized as the correct users)?

Or is there a way to newly create a PDC and then use the existing information from AzureAD?
As ADConnect does not provide this functionality in this direction as is documented by Microsoft.

**UPDATE**
The more I crawl the internet and gather information it looks like I have to setup a Domain besides the AzureAD as long as there are users using the AzureAD logins for their laptops. And keep the users apart until they get time to make a new setup of the laptop moving their data anyway.
Creating local users I could probably do a soft match but most likely the laptop logins will not be mapped to the correct users.
And for administrative AzureAD users Microsoft strongly discourages to create a domain user and then match them - as all AzureAD properties are overwritten.